# Referencing dll files in sharepoint event receivers

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, dll, sharepoint-2013

I have a C# Sharepoint 2013 project in Visual Studio, which I connect to a SharePoint 2013 site. I created an event receiver, which fires correctly whenever an element is added to a specific list in SP. I can debug the event receiver and the breakpoints are hit.

However, when I try adding functionality from a referenced dll, the event receiver stops working. The breakpoints are not active - as in "no symbols have been loaded for this document". I then add the DLL to the package in Visual Studio, to the GAC. When debugging, the breakpoints are now "normal"  indicating that symbols have been loaded. Still, no breakpoints are hit.

To clarify, just adding the DLL as a reference works (i.e. breakpoints are hit), it is when modifying the event receiver code to use something from the referenced dll, like creating an object, that the breakpoints stop working.

In a custom event receiver, how do i reference and use functionality from a dll file?

Comment: why are you doing that? :)

Comment: Well, there are methods in the dll which I need to use.

Comment: Try debigging without adding the DLL to gac. Just refer them like you normally do and start debugging.

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing I tried. Then no symbols are loaded at all.

Comment: Look in SharePoint log for any errors. There might be smth like "Could not load file or assembly XXX or one of its dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

Does the event receiver work regardless breakpoints are hit or not? Is your dll signed?

Switch deploy type to No Activation from project settings and activate it manually, if it doesn't help either, normally deploy the project, activate the feature, then go back to visual studio and do "Tools/Attach to process", then attach to appropriate w3wp process and see if there is still a message indicating that no symbols are loaded.

If this doesn't help, remove the reference from that dll and try another one.

Another approach: Install the dll to GAC by command line (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx) and then add reference to the installed dll from your project.

I think one of the approaches should help.